# MySQL "Show table status", auto increment is not correct

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I create a new table in Mysql, add some rows, yet the Auto_increment field of show tables still returns NULL.

The mysql manual says:  this field should return:  "The next Auto_increment value"

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-table-status.html

What am I doing wrong?

How can I find the next auto_increment value correctly?

---

Steps to reproduce:

```
create table `test` (
  `id` int(5) not null auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(256),
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);
```

Then I run :

```
show table status where name like 'test';
```

Result:

```
Name,   Engine,   Version, ...,  Auto_increment, ... 
'test', 'InnoDB', '10',    ...,  NULL, ...
```

Then I run:

```
insert into test values(null,'name1');
insert into test values(null,'name2');
insert into test values(null,'name3');
```

Edit: -other insert syntax-

```
insert into test (name) values('name4');
insert into test (name) values('name5');
insert into test (name) values('name6');
```

Fetch the status of the table

```
show table status where name like 'test';
```

Result

```
Name,   Engine,   Version, ...,  Auto_increment, ... 
'test', 'InnoDB', '10',    ...,  NULL, ...
```

Data in the table

```
select * from test;
```

Result:

```
1   name1
2   name2
3   name3
```

For your information:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
```

Result:

```
'innodb_version', '8.0.12'
'protocol_version', '10'
'slave_type_conversions', ''
'tls_version', 'TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2'
'version', '8.0.12'
'version_comment', 'MySQL Community Server - GPL'
'version_compile_machine', 'x86_64'
'version_compile_os', 'Win64'
'version_compile_zlib', '1.2.11'
```

edit:
autocommit:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "autocommit";
```

result:

```
'autocommit', 'ON'
```

Edit:

After a while it automagically starts working.  No clear reason how to make it start working.

Comment: This might be a bug..

Comment: You have set id to `null` do not know why it still have value

Comment: Using the more ANSI SQL insert with column names also seams "broken" https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k32zMPXKk4pJj6KGg1Zo2j/0 .. it works on MySQL 5.7 https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k32zMPXKk4pJj6KGg1Zo2j/1 so i assume this is a MySQL 8.0 bug

Comment: @JDC:  autocommit variable is set or not in your mysql.

Comment: @Suresh   SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "autocommit";    -->    'autocommit', 'ON'

Comment: if you have an auto_increment field you can completely skip it in the insert statement. Does it happen the same if you just do: `insert into test values('name1');` and so on completely omitting the value for the id?

Comment: @LelioFaieta  This does not work!! Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: @JDC you have to remove both the value (`null`) *and* the column name (`Auto_increment`) in the SQL insert query

Comment: @Martin    Both syntaxes work.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a feature.. not a bug.

The table statistics are cached.  To disable the cache and always have the latest version you should change the server variable that indicates the duration of the cache-clear to 0:

```
SET PERSIST information_schema_stats_expiry = 0
```

The default value of this property has changed to 86400 (24 hours) in Mysql 8.x

Example:

```
SET PERSIST information_schema_stats_expiry = 86400
-- 86400 is the default value of mysql 8.x  if you have never changed this you don't need to set this


show variables like 'information_schema_stats_expiry';

+---------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                   | Value |
+---------------------------------+-------+
| information_schema_stats_expiry | 86400 |
+---------------------------------+-------+

create schema mytest;

create table `test` (
    `id` int(5) not null auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(256),
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);

insert into test values(null,'name1')
insert into test values(null,'name2')
insert into test values(null,'name3')

show table status where name like 'test';
+------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time         | Check_time | Collation          | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| test | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    |    3 |           5461 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              4 | 2018-10-09 15:32:15 | 2018-10-09 15:32:16 | NULL       | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
-- The Auto_increment field is correctly set to 4.. but is now cached.

insert into test values(null,'name3');

show table status where name like 'test';
+------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time         | Check_time | Collation          | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| test | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    |    3 |           5461 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              4 | 2018-10-09 15:32:15 | 2018-10-09 15:32:16 | NULL       | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
-- The Auto_increment is still 4 (it was cached).

drop schema mytest
```

Now we change the configuration:

```
SET PERSIST information_schema_stats_expiry = 0
```

and we run the same test:

```
show variables like 'information_schema_stats_expiry'


+---------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                   | Value |
+---------------------------------+-------+
| information_schema_stats_expiry | 0     |
+---------------------------------+-------+

create schema mytest;
create table `test` (
    `id` int(5) not null auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(256),
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);

insert into test values(null,'name1');
insert into test values(null,'name2');
insert into test values(null,'name3');

show table status where name like 'test';

+------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time         | Check_time | Collation          | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| test | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    |    3 |           5461 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              4 | 2018-10-09 15:32:49 | 2018-10-09 15:32:49 | NULL       | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
--  Auto_increment is 4, but the result is not cached!

insert into test values(null,'name3');



show table status where name like 'test';


+------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time         | Check_time | Collation          | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| test | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    |    4 |           4096 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              5 | 2018-10-09 15:32:49 | 2018-10-09 15:32:49 | NULL       | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
-- The  Auto_increment field is now 5 (a correct, not cached value)

drop schema mytest;
```

Comment: I have to execute `SET PERSIST information_schema_stats_expiry = 0` everyday, How to do something that prevent this from happening?