# MySQL: Why does my INSERT statement skip 56 numbers when auto-incrementing the id?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

While demonstrating the INSERT statement to the students of my SQL course, we've come up on some odd behavior in MySQL 8.0. Please help us learn what is happenning. (No need for workarounds as we're aware of a few and this is for learning, not for production. Thank you)

We are creating a new database and copying some rows from the well-known [Sakila](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/) sample DB, like so:

```
CREATE DATABASE simpsons;

USE simpsons;

CREATE TABLE `character` (
    character_id smallint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(20),
    shoe_size INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (character_id));

INSERT INTO `character` 
        (first_name, last_name)
    SELECT 
        first_name, last_name 
    FROM 
        sakila.actor;
```

When we do this and ``` SELECT * FROM ``character`` ``` we see that all 200 records from `sakila.actor` have been copied correctly over to the new `character` table.

The last row gets the value `200` for its `character_id` auto-incremented PK. The output window shows no errors in any of the above commands.

Then, when we immediately add one more record manually:

```
INSERT INTO `character`
    (first_name, last_name, shoe_size)
VALUES
    ('Bart', 'Simpson', 35);
```

Quite oddly, we find that this record gets the value `256` as its `character_id` and not `201`.

This is despite the fact that running `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';` shows that both `auto_increment_increment` and `auto_increment_offset` are set to `1`.

**We would like to learn *why* does MySQL skip 56 numbers?**

---

*Please note, this question is different from [MySQL InnoDB auto_increment value increases by 2 instead of 1. Virus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590391/mysql-innodb-auto-increment-value-increases-by-2-instead-of-1-virus) and [MySQL autoincrement column jumps by 10- why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206751/mysql-autoincrement-column-jumps-by-10-why) because `auto_incerement_increment` is 1, there are no DELETE operations in our (easily reproducible) scenario and we each are the only users of our prospective DBs. Plus none of the answers to that question are conclusive as to what actually happened. Finally, please see @Postman's wonderful answer which references a root cause not mentioned in any of the answers to the above questions. Thank you*

Comment: A) Who cares? B) Possibly: Abandoned transactions. C) To find out what the next value *should* be, check `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. D) You can always switch it to whatever you want with `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: Try and use `VARCHAR(255)` as a default and only restrict that if you have a very compelling reason. For many things, like names and email addresses, shorter fields can cause huge hassles for your users.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL InnoDB auto\_increment value increases by 2 instead of 1. Virus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590391/mysql-innodb-auto-increment-value-increases-by-2-instead-of-1-virus)

Comment: @tadman, thank you. A) Obviously, I do. B) Which abandoned transactions? From which command? C) + D) I don't see how these help answer my question, sadly.

Comment: @jorge-campos. Thank you, I've gone over that answer before posting. `auto_increment_increment` is 1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL autoincrement column jumps by 10- why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206751/mysql-autoincrement-column-jumps-by-10-why)

Comment: @Schwern thank you, but it doesn't. `auto_incerement_increment` is set to `1` and we're not using `IGNORE`.

Comment: Can confirm this behavior for MySQL version 8.0.20

Comment: @Progman thank you :). Was starting to feel like maybe my students and I were having a shared a hallucination LOL.

Comment: How to reproduce: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=230c603619b55a3e0dbd0590ce91e398

Comment: @Progman This is curious. Repeated insert into select doesn't change targetTable's auto_increment. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c4201c799c775cab1337b2d616d6bd70

Comment: @Schwern Might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52705477/mysql-show-table-status-auto-increment-is-not-correct. When you use a simple `SELECT` you see the correct allocated ids.

Comment: @Progman thanks but I don't see how the stats caching could (normally) have this effect. I've tried `SET PERSIST information_schema_stats_expiry = 0;` with both our repro and yours and the results are still the same (256 and 8 respectively).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior has something to do with ["bulk inserts"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-lock-modes) and the [`innodb_autoinc_lock_mode`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_autoinc_lock_mode) setting.

As far as I understand it (the documentation isn't quite clear about this), when you use a `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` statement, MySQL cannot know how many rows are actually being inserted before running the query, but the IDs for the new AUTO_INCREMENT values have to be reserved when using `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=1` (consecutive) or `2` (interleaved). From my observation it reserves a set of AUTO_INCREMENT numbers where the count is a power of 2 (cannot confirm this, only a guess). See the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE sourceTable(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE targetTable(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    original VARCHAR(30)
);

INSERT INTO sourceTable(name) VALUES ('one');
INSERT INTO sourceTable(name) VALUES ('two');
INSERT INTO sourceTable(name) VALUES ('three');
INSERT INTO sourceTable(name) VALUES ('four');
INSERT INTO sourceTable(name) VALUES ('five');

INSERT INTO targetTable(original) SELECT name FROM sourceTable;

INSERT INTO targetTable(original) VALUES ('manual');

SELECT * FROM targetTable;
```

This will generate the following output:

```
+----+----------+
| id | original |
+----+----------+
|  1 | one      |
|  2 | two      |
|  3 | three    |
|  4 | four     |
|  5 | five     |
|  8 | manual   |
+----+----------+
```

When inserting the 5 rows from the source table, it reserves the next 8 possible AUTO_INCREMENT values because that is the closest power of 2 number greater than 5. However, it will use only 5 of them since you insert only 5 rows.

In your case, you are inserting 200 rows, so the closest power of 2 number greater than 200 would be 256. So you have a "gap" of 56 missing AUTO_INCREMENT values and the next entry gets the ID 256.

Comment: Now I'm curious - How does MySQL know which power of 2 to use?

Comment: @urig Unknown (and keep in mind that my assumption is just speculation). Maybe it's some kind of iteration process where bigger slot ranges are reserved while reading the source data. So it might reserve `1` at the beginning, than one additional `1`, then `2`, then `4`, then `8`,... until it reserves a final slot range of `128` (to the already used `128` IDs) to fill the remaining rows from the original `200` rows. But again, just speculation.

Comment: From having read the article (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-lock-modes) I thought the reservation of auto-inc values was done once, at the beginning of execution? How come it's done iteratively? And why are the increments throttling up? I wish someone who knows the code would chime in LOL

Comment: @urig I may be wrong, but I think it is simply finding the next power of 2 that is greater than the current max(auto_inc). So for instance, I have a table that had 10,013 rows and the max id# was also 10,013. Then I did a bulk insert, and my next id# was 16,384. (10^13 = 8,192 < 10,013 .... 10^14 = 16,384 > 10,013, so 16,384 is chosen)

Comment: This answer confirms the theory that this is a power of 2, and includes a link to the source code:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/326639